# Python3 venv: Can env directory be renamed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows.
I have created a virtual environment with

> python c:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\pyvenv.py foo

Then activated it

> foo\Scripts\activate.bat

And installed several libraries in it.

Question: Is it safe to rename the venv folder "foo" to "bar"?
I.e. once i have renamed foo to bar, then activate it with

> bar\Scripts\activate.bat

will it still work?

What could make problems are any environment variable settings and absolute paths.

Comment: Why not try it and give it a go?

Comment: @Torxed, I renamed it, and it didn't work. It had several hard-coded paths in the files. I've even used sed to fix the paths, but still something was broken. (note: I'm on Linux)

Comment: 1: You sad "will it still work" - Try instead of ask, you're more likely to get help by telling us the problem instead of asking "will this cause problems" :P 2: You're mentioning .bat scripts, but you're on linux? Which one is it?

Comment: @Torxed I think the question is perfectly valid as it is. Trying is not always a good way to convince oneself whether something is possible/recommended. This very question/issue is an example of exactly that: typically, just trying can seemingly "work" at first; problems can appear slowly and later. See e.g. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88452. (Recommending a user to indicate in the question whether they tried or not, and what the result was, is not wrong though. But it's not "Try instead of ask", but rather "Do ask, also try it, and indicate what happened".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do that you should use `virtualenv`. From the [docs](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html?highlight=relocatable#making-environments-relocatable):

> Normally environments are tied to a specific path. That means that you cannot move an environment around or copy it to another computer. You can fix up an environment to make it relocatable with the command:
>
> $ virtualenv --relocatable ENV
>
> This will make some of the files created by setuptools or distribute use relative paths, and will change all the scripts to use activate_this.py instead of using the location of the Python interpreter to select the environment.
>
> Note: you must run this after you've installed any packages into the environment. If you make an environment relocatable, then install a new package, you must run virtualenv --relocatable again.

But be aware:

> The --relocatable option currently has a number of issues, and is not guaranteed to work in all circumstances. It is possible that the option will be deprecated in a future version of virtualenv.

Comment: Broken link. Currently https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/?highlight=relocatable#making-environments-relocatable