# How to add all the dependencies of the python project within the project?

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, python-module

I install the project dependencies with **pip**. Pip install all its dependencies to this location

Location: **/home/tara/taraproject/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages**

> What I want to accomplish:

I want to put all the dependencies with the project rather than making the users to set it up during the operations.Just trying to remove the installation burden to the operation team.

**What I tried ?**

I tried this inside my ProjectFolder,where my working project exist

***/home/tara/taraprject/ProjectFolder***

I  created a directory called dependencies and tried to  add all the dependencies module inside it.Than made an import as.

```
from dependencies.yapsy.PluginManager import PluginManager
```

I have also made the directory as modules by adding the **init**.py file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    from dependencies.yapsy.PluginManager import PluginManager
  File "/home/tara/taraproject/myvenv/checkaccess/dependencies/yapsy/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from yapsy.compat import is_py2, str
ImportError: No module named yapsy.compat
```

Looks like the import was working but the internal code of the modules had an error with such import.

**Why Trying So ?**

If I can do so the operation team can just get my project and run it easily without a need to download the dependencies and make necessary setup.Just want to make the operation part easier

**How do I fix such problems or what is the way to do it ?**

Comment: By putting it in `dependencies`, you are changing the module's absolute import paths and therefore easily break them. It would be more promising not to make `dependencies` a python package, but to add it to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable while keeping your import statements as before.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description provided I believe virtual environments could provide a solution to your question. From the introduction on virtual environments (see links below):

> Python applications will often use packages and modules that don’t
> come as part of the standard library. Applications will sometimes need
> a specific version of a library, because the application may require
> that a particular bug has been fixed or the application may be written
> using an obsolete version of the library’s interface.
>
> This means it may not be possible for one Python installation to meet the requirements of every application. If application A needs
> version 1.0 of a particular module but application B needs version
> 2.0, then the requirements are in conflict and installing either version 1.0 or 2.0 will leave one application unable to run.
>
> The solution for this problem is to create a virtual environment, a self-contained directory tree that contains a Python installation
> for a particular version of Python, plus a number of additional
> packages.
>
> Different applications can then use different virtual environments. To resolve the earlier example of conflicting requirements, application A can have its own virtual environment with version 1.0 installed while application B has another virtual environment with version 2.0. If application B requires a library be upgraded to version 3.0, this will not affect application A’s environment.

More information on virtual environments can be found at (quick internet search):

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html (Python 3)
- http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ (Python 2)
- https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Hope this helps.

**edit:** following the comment. Virtual environments can become relocatable using the relocatable option. From the user guide (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#making-environments-relocatable):

> Normally environments are tied to a specific path. That means that you cannot  move an environment around or copy it to another computer. You can fix up an environment to make it relocatable

See also: [Python3 venv: Can env directory be renamed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946719/python3-venv-can-env-directory-be-renamed)

Hope this gives a solution to your problem.

Comment: All the packages are installed in virtualenv generated folder now and that is not a problem . Problem is I want to put it in my own project directory and thus the end user don't have to set it up again.